# getting & setting spark.driver/executor.extraClassPath on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, emr

As far as I can tell, when setting / using `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` on AWS EMR within the `spark-defaults.conf` or elsewhere as a flag, I would have to first get the existing value that `[...].extraClassPath` is set to, then append `:/my/additional/classpath` to it in order for it to work.

is there a function in Spark that allows me to to just append an *additional* class path to it where it retains/respects the existing paths set by EMR in `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`?

Comment: You want to override spark default conf ?

Comment: @eliasah no, but i do want to programmatically kick off an EMR job and not have to SSH into it and manually GET then SET the extraClassOptions...and the way that EMR already has extraClassOptions set makes it hard to just add an additional class path to whats already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such "function" in Spark but:
On EMR AMI's you can write a bootstrap that will append/set whatever you want in spark-defaults, will of course affect all Spark jobs.

When EMR moved to the newer "release-label" this stopped working as bootstrap-steps were replaced with configuration JSONs and the manual bootstraps run before applications are installed ( At least when I tried it )

Answer (score 0):

We use SageMaker Studio connected to EMR clusters via Apache Livy and none of the approaches suggested so far worked for me - we need to add a custom JAR on the classpath for a custom filesystem.

Following this guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-spark-classnotfoundexception/

I made it work by adding an EMR Step to cluster set up with the following code (this is TypeScript CDK, passed into `steps` parameter of `CfnCluster` CDK construct:

```
  //We are using this approach to add CkpFS JAR (in Docker image additional-jars) onto the class path because
  // the spark.jars configuration in spark-defaults is not respected by Apache Livy on EMR when it creates a Spark session
  // AWS guide followed: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-spark-classnotfoundexception/
  private createStepToAddCkpFSJAROntoEMRSparkClassPath() {
    return {
      name: "AddCkpFSJAROntoEMRSparkClassPath",
      hadoopJarStep: {
        jar: "command-runner.jar",
        args: [
          "bash",
          "-c",
          "while [ ! -f /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf ]; do sleep 1; done;" +
            "sudo sed -i '/spark.*.extraClassPath/s/$/:\\/additional-jars\\/\\*/' /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf",
        ],
      },
      actionOnFailure: "CONTINUE",
    };
  }
```